# SSL Error (Port=443) Max retries exceeded when trying to import osmnx data in Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ssl-certificate, osmnx

When trying to run this line
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')
I get this error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?format=json&polygon_geojson=1&dedupe=0&limit=50&q=Piedmont%2C+CA%2C+USA (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

I googled and found this could be a solution but I got the same error message:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geopy.geocoders.options.default_user_agent = 'my_app/1'
geopy.geocoders.options.default_timeout = 7
geolocator = Nominatim()
print(geolocator.headers)
{'User-Agent': 'my_app/1'}
print(geolocator.timeout)
```

*(I changed my/app_1 to "ABC" in the code above)*

I also tried - since that was in another solution on stackoverflow, this:

```
pip install certifi
```

but the same SSL-error appeared.

I'm using Anaconda Navigator 2.1.1 on Mac (OS Big Sur) and Jupiter Notebook 6.3.0

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please? I'm behind a company proxy and assume that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this URL work in your browser:
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org//search?format=json&polygon_geojson=1&dedupe=0&limit=50&q=Piedmont%2C+CA%2C+USA

you can also set request params:
`ox.config(request_kwargs={})`

Comment: It's now: `ox.settings.requests_kwargs = {'verify': False}`